# How can I add extra data to a file field?

Tags: entities

I am using Drupal 7's core module, file.

The file field array looks like this:

```
[field_game] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [fid] => 57
                        [display] => 1
                        [description] => the-pyro-guy.swf
                        [uid] => 0
                        [filename] => the-pyro-guy.swf
                        [uri] => public://swf/the-pyro-guy_2.swf
                        [filemime] => application/x-shockwave-flash
                        [filesize] => 5506729
                        [status] => 1
                        [timestamp] => 1346017444
                        [rdf_mapping] => Array
                            (
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

In addition to the above data, I want to store keys containing the game's height and width in this same file field. Can I do this, preferably in code?

Answer (score 3):

You can't by default, but check out the [File Entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module.

> This module extends the core file entity, making it a full fledged
>   entity, allowing for fields, display formatters, and more.

This allows you to add fields (such as a height/width field) to files in the same way that you add fields any other fieldable entity (nodes, terms etc...).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Doing so goes against drupal design; drupal won't let you do that.

Instead, create a new field with the data you want, then group the two fields together using something like [Fieldgroup](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)

Answer (score 0):

I am having good luck getting SWF dimensions automatically with PHP [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)